# form tag is printed out of bounadries for the first message only

Tags: php, html

i have a form that is being printed for each message in my loop. this form is very important as it is the form that allows users to favorite a certain message. the problem is that for the first message the form is not being printed, but for all other messages it is being printed correctly and prints the buttons inside the form. only the first instance of a message is not being printed properly and is being out of bounds of the button.

My html and php :

```
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_id=? ORDER BY msgid DESC");
        $result->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $result->execute();
     while ($row = $result->fetch())
        {
            $msg_id=$row['msgid'];
            $from_id = $row['from_id'];
            $blockusername=$_SESSION['active_user'];

            $to_id = $row['to_id'];
            $d=$row['date'];

        //start recieved messages 
        if($_GET['a'] == "recieved") 
        {
            $msg_id=$row['msgid'];


            ?>



<div Class="inside-card" <td>
    <div class="msg-body">
        <p><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>

    </div>

    <div class="msg-action">

<form class='favourite-form' name='favform' method='post' > <!-- here is the form that should be printed for each message propertly, but is not being properly printed for the first message-->
      <a class="msg-icon " href="<?php echo "reply?message=" . $row['msgid'] . ""; ?>"></a>
       <button type="submit" name="fav"  value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>" > <i class="far fa-heart" ></i></a></button>


</form>

        <span class="msg-icon action-toggler" style="float:right;">
           <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i>
            <ul class="action-dropdown">

                <li>
                    <a class="msg-icon " onclick="openReportModal('<?php echo $row['msgid'];?>','<?php echo $row['text']?>')">
                        Report

                    </a>


                </li>

                <li>

                    <a class="msg-icon " onclick="openBlockModal('<?php echo $from_id;?>','<?php echo $blockusername?>')" >
                        Block
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="msg-icon" onclick="openDeleteModal(<?php echo $row['msgid'] ?>)" >Delete</a>
                </li>


            </ul>



        </span>

        <span class="msg-icon"
            style="float:right; margin-right:12px; font-size:12px;"><?php echo timeAgo($d); ?></span>

    </div>

    </td>
    </tr>

</div>
```

what is causing the form to be out of bounds for the first message only, i am struggling to understand this issue as there shouldnt be any?

please refer to the image below to see the code from elements in the developer tools 
[[Code from elements tab][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akRco.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akRco.png)

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the output which are you getting right now?

Comment: issue is fixed, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue, there was a table tag that was causing the form to be out of bounds for the first message as the table tag was right before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this, the error is still there?

```
<form class="favourite-form" name="favform" method="post"> <!-- here is the form that should be printed for each message propertly, but is not being properly printed for the first message-->
    <a class="msg-icon" href="<?php echo("reply?message=" . $row['msgid'] . ""); ?>"></a>
      <button type="submit" name="fav" value="<?php echo($row['msgid']); ?>">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: i found the issue, it was a table that was unneeded causing the problem. thank you!

Comment: just saw it too :D